# I wrote a jQuery script that I would like to add to my website powered by Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Does wordpress automatically load jQuery?
Because I have a script(in jQuery, and I use $.) that I would like to execute in a particular page (not all pages), but wordpress doesn't seem to compile jQuery?
I tried changing all the '$' with 'jQuery', still nothing.

Did anyone had the same problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

WordPress loads jQuery but in no conflict mode. Replace "$" with "jQuery" and your script will work.

Make sure you are using the enqueue function of WordPress within your functions.php file. In order to do this, place the following in your functions.php file:

```
function myScriptFunction() {
   wp_enqueue_script(
       'custom-script',
       get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js',
       array( 'jquery' )
   );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myScriptFunction' );
```

What you're telling WordPress is to load up your script and that it needs jQuery as a dependency. Otherwise jQuery will not load because there would be no reason to send it to the user.